# Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code? When I press rename for the 11th time(in order for the number to be 10) everything freezes

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter

The for-loop in `function-Click()` is probably freezing the whole program but I can't figure out why.

Code:

```
#IMPORTS

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

#VARIABLES


final=[]
a=0
text1=""

#APP

win = Tk()
win.title('App')
win.geometry('500x500')

mytext = Entry(win, width=50)
mytext.pack()
mytext.get()

scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(win)
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

listbox = tk.Listbox(win, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
listbox.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)

scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

#FUNCTIONS

def Click():
    global a
    global text1
    global final
    listbox.delete(0,tk.END)
    text1=str(a) + str(mytext.get())
    final.append(text1)
    for i in final:
        if a == 10:
            r='0'+i
            final.append(r)
        listbox.insert(tk.END,i)
    mytext.delete(0,END)
    a+=1
```

I want a programm that will show enumerated numbers in my listbox but each time the number becomes 10 all the other previous numbers get an extra zero in front of them so that they still are enumerated. For example: 0,1,2....9,10(when it reaches 10 all the other become 00,01,02,03...09,10)

```
def Click2():
    mytext.delete(0,END)
    global a
    a=0

##BUTTONS
    
btn1 = ttk.Button(win, text='Rename', command=Click)
btn1.pack()

btn2=ttk.Button(win, text='Startover',command=Click2)
btn2.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's not usually a good idea to modify a list you're iterating over inside the loop. Also, a debugger can be your best friend when you can't figure out what your code is up to.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are modifying the original list `final` while iterating over it. This `for` loop is causing the problem.

```
for i in final:
    if a == 10:
        r='0'+i
        final.append(r)
    listbox.insert(tk.END,i)
```

Here, if value of `a` is 10, the loop will become an infinite loop and thats why everything freezes. **I'm not sure what are you trying to do** with this code but iterating over a copy of list while modifying the original list may help.

Like this:

```
for i in final[:]:
    if a == 10:
        r='0'+i
        final.append(r)
    listbox.insert(tk.END,i)
```